# Picking a suitable resolution for a modern low-res game?

Tags: opengl, sfml, screen, resolution, pixel

I'm working on a 2D game project right now (using SFML+OpenGL and C++) and I'm trying to figure out how to go about choosing a resolution. I want my game to have a pixel resolution that is around that of classic '16bit' era consoles like the Super Nintendo or Neo Geo. However, I'd also like to have my game fit the 16:9 aspect ratio that most modern PC monitors use. Finally I'd like to be able to include an option for running full screen.

I know that I could create my own low-res 16:9 resolution that is more-or-less around the size of SNES or NeoGeo games. However, the problem seems to be that doing so would leave me with a non-standard resolution that my monitor would not be able to support in fullscreen mode.

For example, if i divide the common 16:9 resolution 1920x1080 by 4, I would get a 16:9 resolution that is relatively close to the resolution used by 16bit era games; 480x270.
That would be fine in a windowed mode, but I don't think that it would be supported in fullscreen mode.

How can I choose a resolution that suits my needs? Can I use something like 480x270? If so, how would I go about getting fullscreen mode to work with such a non-standard resolution? (I'm guessing OpenGL/SFML might have a way of up-scaling...but..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the right answer yourself - you will have to render things to an off-screen buffer and upscale it to any of the supported resolutions. This will be very easy since oldschool games didn't have anything better than nearest neighbor interpolation anyway.

If you use GPU for this, it's possible to avoid a resolution switch (upscaling to large resolutions can cost quite a lot of CPU time otherwise).

It would also allow the use of better upscaling algorithms, if you're interested. I'd highly suggest looking into these, at least for the people with bigger monitors than whatever laptops usually offer since nearest neighbor interpolation will look really bad for those people. They usually also have a good GPU so it isn't much of an implementation problem.